# RecyclerView Swipe with a view below not detecting click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` row layout like this

```
<Layout>
    <BackgroundView>        
    <ForegroundView>
</Layout>
```

I am using `ItemTouchHelper` to handle swipes (partial) on the foreground view like

```
@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
    adapter.onItemSwiped(viewHolder);
}

@Override
public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                        float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

    View foregroundView = ((myViewHolder)viewHolder).getForegroundView();
    getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

    //getSwipeLimit() used below returns the width of the delete icon
    float translationX = Math.min(-dX, ((myViewHolder) viewHolder).getSwipeLimit());
    foregroundView.setTranslationX(-translationX);
}
```

I have set a click listener for the backgroundview in the `BindViewHolder` of my adapter class.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(WhiteListViewHolder holder, Cursor cursor) {
    //get name and number from the cursor here

    holder.name.setText(name);
    holder.number.setText(number);

    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("whitelist", "yes clicked");
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, the background view is accepting clicks when the view is not swiped but after the view is swiped out, the background view stops accepting clicks.

[image]

Referring the above image, if I click on the delete button, the swiped view is recovered sometimes and it doesn't captures the click.

If I let the whole view swipe out, clicking the empty space left also brings back the swiped view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share your project in Github so that I could give it a try?

Comment: @ReazMurshed You can find project here: https://github.com/amk47/testproject

Comment: Checkout this library : This is what I've used in a project, it works perfectly for me. Let me know if it helps : https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout

Comment: I  know about this library but  I want to achieve this task with the `ItemTouchHelper`. I will try the library after failing to do so. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Have you resolve this? I Met the same issue

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue?

Comment: Does any one has the solution?

Comment: does anyone find any sol?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue with `ItemTouchHelper`. Calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onSwiped(..)` fixed the issue for me.

```
ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, LEFT) {
        override fun onMove(
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        ): Boolean = false

        override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
            //calling my listeners here

            recycler_view.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
            if (viewHolder != null) {
                getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(viewHolder.itemView.view_foreground)
            }
        }

        override fun onChildDrawOver(
            c: Canvas,
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?,
            dX: Float,
            dY: Float,
            actionState: Int,
            isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
        ) {
            if (dX < 0 && viewHolder != null) {
                getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(
                    c,
                    recyclerView,
                    viewHolder.itemView.view_foreground,
                    dX,
                    dY,
                    actionState,
                    isCurrentlyActive
                )
            }
        }

        override fun onChildDraw(
            c: Canvas,
            recyclerView: RecyclerView,
            viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            dX: Float,
            dY: Float,
            actionState: Int,
            isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
        ) {
            if (dX < 0) {
                getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(
                    c,
                    recyclerView,
                    viewHolder.itemView.view_foreground,
                    dX,
                    dY,
                    actionState,
                    isCurrentlyActive
                )
            }
        }
    }).also {
        it.attachToRecyclerView(recycler_view)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the first part of the task - now did not detect without swipe.
But the click do not detect after swipe...

```
 @Override
 public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
   if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE){
     if (dX < 0) {
         backgroundView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
     else {
         backgroundView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }
   }
 }
```